# Loading json and images situated outside root directory

Tags: javascript, css, json

I'm trying to load a json file and some images which are situated in some other directory before my root directory. I am now trying this code to get it. It's working fine, but as it seems it's not the perfect way to do it.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/content/LB/contents/content.json", function(json){
    console.log(json);
}
```

and images

```
<img src="http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/content/LB/contents/locations/locationname/thumbnail.png />
```

I'm trying to load the json and images to

```
http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/content/LB/appdrive/html/someHTML.html
http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/content/LB/appdrive/html/js/someJS.js
```

I'm using only HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT. So the main question is is there any way to change the source of json and images to something like this

```
$.getJSON("folder2/folder3/content/LB/contents/content.json", function(json){
    console.log(json);
}
```

and image

```
<img src="../folder2/folder3/content/LB/contents/locations/locationname/thumbnail.png />
```

And one more thing to say, FOLDER2 is the root directory.

Comment: Yes. You can root your URLs to the root of the website (e.g., '/folder2/folder3/.../content.json'). Note the leading slash.

Comment: @ventaur So I tried it this way " $.getJSON("/folder2/folder3/content/LB/contents/content.json", function(json){ " it didn't work

Comment: @ventaur ok it worked. I was neglecting folder1. So I changed it to " $.getJSON("/folder1/folder2/folder3/content/LB/contents/content.json", function(json){ " and it worked as expected. And it didn't work before as I didn't use the leading slash. So your comment helped a lot. Can you post it as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can "root" your URLs to the root of the website (e.g., '/folder1/folder2/folder3/.../content.json'). Note the leading slash.